# How to hide a checkbox behind a DIV

Tags: css, html, checkbox, hide, visibility

```
<div style="padding-top:5px; overflow:hidden; font-size:13px;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <div style="background-color:blue; width:20px;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" style="z-index:-1;" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        Remember Me
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <a href="" id="forgotpassword"> Forgot Password ? </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the checkbox behind the parent DIV.

I tried `VISIBILITY:HIDDEN;` for the checkbox, but I wanted to make a jQuery function where I click on this checkbox and something should happen, but it didnt happen when it was hidden, when I showed it back again, it worked, so I don't wanna use `HIDDEN`, but i wanna put it behind the div, so it doesn't show up.

this code isn't working, I used `z-index=-1`, and later `z-index:20` for the parent DIV, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to hide the checkbox behind your div.

Try using `display:none;` on the element:

```css
#rememberme {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I wanna make a customized checkbox later, this is just a test, the background-color is just a test, if I use display:none, then how could I click it?

Comment: In that case, why do you need a checkbox at all ? Use small divs instead, on which you can add your click event and the corresponding actions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Ali, Now you can  customized checkbox, here is example http://jsfiddle.net/chanduzalte/7rSug/3/